# How to use stdeva in an excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

this line is giving me an error,please help me to troubleshoot

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=STDEVA(range(" & """" & area & """" & ")"
```

here area is a string variable which is having the value it supposed to have just fine

So the main issue is syntax and more specifically the quotation marks I guess,any help is appreciated,even though I can use stdev I still like to use stdeva in my macro although the difference is very subtle.

Comment: A hint here - use `Debug.Print "=STDEVA(range(" & """" & area & """" & ")"` and compare the output in the Immediate window to what the formula should be in the worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that `area` is a String`:

```
Sub gahgsd()
    Dim area As String
    area = "A1:A4"
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=STDEVA(" & Range(area).Address & ")"
End Sub
```

or:

```
Sub gahgsd()
    Dim area As String
    area = "A1:A4"
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=STDEVA(" & area & ")"
End Sub
```